What is the name of the cartoon where the apocalypse occurs in 1994?

Plot details of any scenes you remember


I can't remember any particular plots, it was an episodic kids TV cartoon.    

Descriptions of any characters or locations


sword and sandal type characters, a family, monsters 
post apocalyptic Earth 

Where you watched the movie or TV show


Watched on Cartoon Network

When you watched the movie or TV show


I watched this in the early 90's before Cartoon Network had it's own shows

Any idea of how old it was


Probably from the 1960's (or early 70's)

Any idea of country of origin (if known)


Quite American

Whether it was animated or not


yes, looked like a Hanna-Barbera cartoon, characters were about as tall as Shaggy

Any other distinctive detail


Every episode started with "In the year 1994" an then a dam bursts and the entire world is destroyed (which is the plot of the show)


I thought it was the "herculoids" but I watched the beginning of one of those shows on YouTube and it wasn't it.  I just remember watching this old 60's show on cartoon network around 1996 and busting a gut every time they said "in the year 1994".

Can you give any details? Characters, storylines, anything at all?

This is Thundarr the Barbarian (1980), where the intro features a voice over "In the year 1994" and depicts a rogue planet doing a flyby which breaks the moon in half and pulls the ozone layer with it, then cuts to a mega-tsunami, hilarity ensues and 2000 years later mutant man-creature mutants are throwing pristine pink VW Beetles at people. ( Intro here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhAobPugvsk )

Alas @yorik Thank you!    1994,  that makes much more sense.

@Yorik I suggest you post it as an answer now.

It's probably Thundarr the Barbarian
It happen in 3994 but the apocalypse have had taken place in 1994. The moon was split in half by a planet that travelled between moon and earth.
